# How to solve Android Studio error : " org.json.JSONException: Value <!doctype of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject"

Tags: android-studio, jsonparser

I'm new in Android Studio, and I'm phasing following problem.
I try to parse into android a data from my server.
The data are created using a php files with the needed sql statement. I test it using the Json Parser Online tool which show the needed result I think.
[Json Parser Online view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1vwZc.png)

In android studio, I have the following code :

The import in the activity :
`

```
import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonObjectRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
```

`

The code in the activity

```
private void jsonParse() {
    
    Log.d("Liste", "Point 0");


JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null,
        new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

            @Override


            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                Log.d("Liste", "Point 1");
                Log.d("Liste", response.toString()  );
                try {

                    JSONArray jsonArray = response.getJSONArray("Partie");
                    iL = jsonArray.length();

                    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {

                        JSONObject partieListe = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                        String PartieId = partieListe.getString("PartieId");
                        String Date = partieListe.getString("Date");
                        String Joueur = partieListe.getString("Joueur");
                        String Parcours = partieListe.getString("Parcours");

                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "error: ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
    @Override

    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
        error.printStackTrace();
        Log.d("Liste", error.getMessage()  );

     }

  });
}
```

running the app, the log show me the following messages :

Liste: Point 0
Liste: Point 3
Liste: org.json.JSONException: Value <!doctype of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject

the sequence even did not went through Point 1

What is wrong in my approach, in my setting .

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution ..

forgot to declare  a requestQueue

RequestQueue requestQueueListe;

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_liste);
```

and add

requestQueueListe.add(requestListe);